# Trying to send email using PHP and then receiving it with SMTP4DEV only logs the session and doesn't return the eamil

Tags: php, email, smtp, apache2.4

I'm using the mail() function built into PHP:

```
mail("test@gmail.com", "test", "hello");
```

I have my PHP.ini setup like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
;smtp_server = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25



; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

I then have SMTP4DEV listening on the same port. Each time I load the web-page a new session log is added to SMTP4DEV but it doesn't actually show the email in the email box. Here is a session log from SMTP4DEV:

```
220 localhost smtp4dev ready
QUIT
221 See you later aligator
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here or how I can view some logs to find the error that is causing this problem?

Comment: See also: [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](//stackoverflow.com/q/24644436)

Comment: Given that [smtp4dev](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev) appears to be a local mail spooler only, you can't expect mails to show up in any inbox (in particular not GMail). But I guess that's your question here. You should raise a bug report, if that's all the logging it does. (Enable the PHP mail.log though as advised in the reference.)

Comment: @mario If I enable mail.log where will the log go? Also I don't want it to show up in Gmail just the SMTP4DEV application